# Vectorized gather operation in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

Given this (sample) data

```
target_slots = np.array([1, 3, 1, 0, 8, 5, 8, 1, 1, 2])
dummy_elements = np.arange(10*D).reshape(10, D)
```

is there any way to express in a vectorized numpy expression the operation

```
gathered_results = np.zeros((num_slots, D))
for i, target in enumerate(target_slots):
    gathered_results[target] += dummy_elements[i]
```

this operation looks like a `bincount` but instead of counting we sum the elements of another array.

(It is implied that `np.max(target_slots)<num_slots` and `np.min(target_slots)>=0` and `target_slots.shape[0] == D`)

Comment: Why is `D  == len(target_slots)`? Doesn't your code actually assume that `len(target_slots) == 10`?

Comment: @Eric I don't think `D` is meant to be `len(target_slots)`. I think it's just a parameter. Can we rollback that edit to what OP had originally?

Comment: I agree @Divakar. `target_slots` has as many elements as the "vectors" in `dummy_elements` (each of size D). One could think of this gather operation as adding the vectors in `dummy_elements` into the respective `target_slots`. So `len(target_slots) == dummy_elements.shape[0]` and `D` is a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You are performing interval-ed summing selecting rows off `dummy_elements` and adding in at specific rows into the output array. So, one obvious choice of a vectorized solution would be with [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html), like so -

```
sidx = target_slots.argsort()
out = np.zeros((num_slots, D))
unq, shift_idx = np.unique(target_slots[sidx],return_index=True)
out[unq] = np.add.reduceat(dummy_elements[sidx],shift_idx)
```

---

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, we can use `np.bincount` as well to perform these ID based summing operations. One way would be with a loop that iterates along the columns of `dummy_elements` and I think would be beneficial when the no. of such columns is comparatively smaller. The implementation would look like this -

```
out = np.zeros((num_slots, D))
L = target_slots.size
for i in range(D):
    out[:,i] = np.bincount(target_slots,dummy_elements[:,i],minlength=L)
```

**Approach #3**

A vectorized version of the same would be like this -

```
L = target_slots.size
ids = (target_slots[:,None] + np.arange(D)*L).ravel('F') 
out = np.bincount(ids,dummy_elements.ravel('F'),minlength=L*D).reshape(D,-1).T
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I understand correctly, this assumes that `target_slots` is "sorted"/interval-ed. So if `target_slots=np.array([8,8, 1, 3, 1, 8, 1, 9, 0, 1])` this wouldn't work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: (I've edited the question to remove the misleading construction of `target_slots` that was sorted, sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @miltos Well we just need to use the sorted indices to index into inputs. Thus, updated solution to handle generic unsorted cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. This now works :) Nevertheless, the problem is that now an O(N) operation requires (the gather operation) requires to sort+unique, which seems to be slower than the original `for` loop (for my data). But I cannot find any better options for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @miltos Check out the just added two more approaches using `bincount`?